# Print different number of a list in a loop

Tags: python, list, loops

I have this array :

```
list = [4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,9,9,9,9]

And i want to use this array like that:

for i in list:
    print(i)
```

Of course here i have this result:

```
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
5.....
```

But i want to print this in my loop without change my list like list[::4], just in my loop:

```
4
5
9
```

In my list I have 4 times the same number and I just want to print 1 number every 4 occurances.

Please help me !

Thanks to reading me !

Comment: Honestly, I do not know what you want, especially if `6` is not even in the list.

Comment: Please, rephrase the question so it's understandable and tell us what have you already tried to solve the problem.  Then we can help you.

Comment: Why not to run your loop over `list[::4]` instead of `list` (which btw is a very bad naming because list is built-in func in python)

Comment: As a side note, you should create variables with the same name as a [builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html), such as `list`.

Comment: You could use `numpy.unique()` or put use `set` other than what you have mentioned already assuming that you get same 4 numbers, you can get the unique one right?

Answer (score 2):

What you looking for is looping with sequence. Please try the below -

```
for x in range(0, len(list), 4):
    print(list[x])
```

Output -

```
4
5
9
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for `set`:

```
lst = [4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,9,9,9,9]
for x in sorted(set(lst)):
    print(x)
```

This yields

```
4
5
9
```

Answer (score 1):

While the solutions in other answers are more elegant, of course you could as well do this manually:

```
print(list[0])
for i in range(1, len(list)):
    if list[i] != list[i-1]:
        print(list[i])
```

While this is neither beautiful nor particularly clever, it gets the job done and you do not need functions that might require taking a peak into the respective documentation ...

If you append your list later and (deliberately or by mistake) don't stick to your four occurrances pattern, this is more flexible than e.g. looping with sequence ...